# What should I name the actions for ajax requests?

Tags: ajax, scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

Let's say I have an  action:

```
def result = Action { Ok(views.html.home.result()) }
```

From `result` view I want to send ajax requests to the server. What's the standard (if any) way to name   the actions that receive such the ajax requests? It might be something like:

```
def getResultAjax(param1: Int) = //....
```

To my mind, it look clumsy.

Your ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such convention in Play, anyway action's name should rather contain info about returned data i.e. `listOfBooks` then just `getResult`.

On the other hand when there's a lot of different methods (some common, other for ajax requests) it can be cleaner if you'll use `ajaxListOfBooks` or create `BooksAjax` controller to handle AJAX request only.

BTW: Purists would say that the requests [`REST's`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) `HTTP methods` should also be taken into account, and then action names can be simplified, pseudo routes:

```
GET     /ajax/books       Books.list
GET     /ajax/books/:id   Books.get(id)
PUT     /ajax/books       Books.create
POST    /ajax/books/:id   Books.update(id)
```